# Remote Node.js Interpreter PhpStorm

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

I followed the instructions given here to install Remote Node.js Interpreter, even after installing and enabling the plugin the Remote Interpreter option is still not available

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configure-node-js-remote-interpreter-dialog.html

Do I need to download the Ultimate edition and then install PHP and Node.js plugin or am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article:

> This menu item is available only when you open the Node.js
>   Interpreters Dialog from the Run/Debug Configuration: Node.js.

Please use Run > Edit run/debug configurations... > Add Node.Js configuration - there will be an option to add remote interpreter

Comment: In addition to the answer/clarification on "why like that": https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25411#comment=27-1906237

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, but I was wondering if a dedicated interpreter can be set from the Settings->Languages & Frameworks.  This method feels a bit weird because my Javascript project is totally independent.